Why can I access the form input values in my parent component?
basically I have 2 blazor components , the child (NewChecklist.razor) is a form that takes input values as parameters that are passed in its parent component (ChecklistManagement.razor). I realized the values werent being recognized in the parent component because when I would try to submit a new Checklist , it was basically an empty list where all the values were missing. At this point I am simply trying to log the value of the first input to the console, and even that I am struggling with
Child Component (NewChecklist.razor) :
@using SFSCheckList.Data.Repos

<h3>NewChecklist</h3>

<p>kahdjakhflkajfke</p>




<form @onsubmit="AddCheckList">
    <div>
        <input @bind-value="Name" label="Title"  Style="width: 25rem"></input>
    </div>
    <div>
        <FluentTextField @bind-Value="Description" label="Description"  Style="width: 25rem"></FluentTextField>
    </div>
    <p></p>
    <div style="display: flex">
        <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
            <label>Start Date</label>
            <FluentDatePicker Value="@(StartDate)" ValueChanged="@(e => StartDate = e.Value)"  />
        </div>
        <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
            <label>End Date</label>
            <FluentDatePicker Value="@EndDate" ValueChanged="@(e => EndDate = e.Value)"  Style="margin-left: 5px;" />
        </div>
    </div>
 

        <button>Submit</button>
    
</form>

@code {
    [Inject]
    protected ChecklistRepo? checklistRepo { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [Parameter]
    public string Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [Parameter]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    [Parameter]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback AddCheckList { get; set; }

    // private async Task SubmitChecklist()
    // {
    //     Console.WriteLine(Name);
    //     Console.WriteLine(Description);
    //     // You can perform further operations like adding the checklist to the database here
    //     await AddCheckList.InvokeAsync();
    // }

}


Parent Component (ChecklistManagement.razor) :
@page "/ManageChecklists"
@using SFSCheckList.Data.Repos
@using SFSCheckList.Components.Checklists

<h3>Checklist Management</h3>
<div style="display: flex;">
    <div style="border: 1px solid black; border-radius: 5px; padding: 1rem; background: #F1F3F9; min-height: 30rem; min-width: 25rem;">
        <CheckListList Checklists="@Checklists" OnChecklistSelected="HandleChecklistSelected" isAddingEnabled="isAddingEnabled" EnableAddChecklist="EnableAddChecklist"/>
    </div>

    <div style="margin-left: 3rem;border: 1px solid black; border-radius: 5px; padding: 1rem; background: #F1F3F9; min-height: 30rem; min-width: 25rem;">
        @if (isAddingEnabled)
        {
            <NewChecklist Name="@ChecklistName" Description="@ChecklistDescription" StartDate="@AvailableStartDate" EndDate="@AvailableEndDate" AddCheckList="SubmitChecklist"/>
        }
        else
        {
            <ChecklistDetails Checklist="SelectedChecklist" EnableEditChecklist="EnableEditChecklist" isEditingEnabled="isEditingEnabled" />
        }
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    [Inject]
    protected ChecklistRepo? checklistRepo { get; set; }

    public bool isAddingEnabled { get; set; } = false;
    public bool isEditingEnabled { get; set; } = false;
    public string ChecklistName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string ChecklistDescription { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public DateTime AvailableStartDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public DateTime AvailableEndDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public SFSCheckList.Data.Models.Checklist? SelectedChecklist { get; set; }
    List<SFSCheckList.Data.Models.Checklist> Checklists = new List<SFSCheckList.Data.Models.Checklist>();

    //enable edit functionality
    public void EnableEditChecklist()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Edit Checklist");
        isEditingEnabled = !isEditingEnabled;
    }

    public void EnableAddChecklist()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Adding Checklist");
        isAddingEnabled = !isAddingEnabled;
    }

    // method to submit checklist
    async Task SubmitChecklist()
    {
        // var newChecklist = new SFSCheckList.Data.Models.Checklist()
        //     {
        //         ChecklistName = ChecklistName,
        //         ChecklistDescription = ChecklistDescription,
        //         AvailableStartDate = AvailableStartDate,
        //         AvailableEndDate = AvailableEndDate,
        //         FY = "2024",
        //         LCTS = DateTime.Now
        //     };

        // await checklistRepo.UpsertChecklist(newChecklist);
        // Checklists.Add(newChecklist);
        // StateHasChanged();
        Console.WriteLine("the Checklist name is " + ChecklistName);
    }


    // method to get checklists
    async Task GetChecklists()
    {
        Checklists = await checklistRepo.GetChecklists();
        var checklists = await checklistRepo.GetChecklists();
        foreach (var checklist in checklists)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(checklist.ChecklistName);
        }
    }
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {     
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
       await GetChecklists();
    }
    // method to handle checklist selected
    private void HandleChecklistSelected(SFSCheckList.Data.Models.Checklist checklist)
    {
        SelectedChecklist = checklist;
        Console.WriteLine($"Checklist Selected:");
        Console.WriteLine($"Name: {checklist.ChecklistName}");
        StateHasChanged();
    }

}


i have tried to access those values in many failed attempts , the ultimate goal is to be able to get all the values from the form (ChecklistName, ChecklistDescription etc) and successfully create a new checklist, as of right now though , im just trying to access the values in a console.writeline statement to make sure its working
